# Self-invoking function + closure to improve hangs due to garbage collection

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection, closures, self-invoking-function

I'm trying to determine whether this pattern will help minimize garbage collection in my Javascript game.

I have a function I call in my main game loop that is defined something like this:

```
my.object.prototype.method = function(some_object) {
    var a,b,c,d,e,f,j,k;

    // initialize variables    
    // do stuff to some_object based on variables...

    return some_object;
}
```

The variables end up being references to objects elsewhere in the code (or numeric values).

I'm trying to decrease the frequency and severity of garbage collection events since they're causing stutters in the frame-rate.

Would refactoring to a self-invoking function that stores the variables in a closure cause the variables to get re-used rather than re-allocated for each function call? Would it have any noticeable effect on GC?

```
my.object.prototype.method = (function() {
    var a,b,c,d,e,f,j,k;

    return function(some_object) {
        // initialize variables
        // do stuff to some_object based on variables...
        // set variables to undefined 

        return some_object;
    }
})();
```

**Note**, these are not objects being allocated in the method; just references to other objects or primitives.

I tried it out and it seems to have made things worse if anything. It seems GC is being done much more frequently and has about the same impact on performance each time (and is collecting about the same amount of memory as before).

Is there  something I'm missing here that might be detracting from performance? Is this going to behave how expected (allocating variables once and re-using them without ever garbage collecting them?) or is there something else going on?

Comment: Why set the variables to `undefiend`? I would think that would make the memory eligible for collection. If the values of the variables are always of the same type, and are primitives, I would think that the memory would be reused if you simply replace the values as needed. Hard to say though. Could be something else in your code doing allocation.

Comment: Setting to undefined so that I'm not retaining a reference to anything unnecessary. For example, one of the objects I reference is a matrix containing the current transformation of the object for this frame. If I only call this once I don't want it to prevent GC of that matrix; the goal here is to avoid creating hundreds of locally scoped vars per frame that need to be GC'd later. Although in thinking about it I'm now wondering how consequential these references are compared to, say, an object primitive.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "object primitive". In JavaScript, that's an oxymoron. But since your variables seem to be holding object references, then yes, if you set the variable to `undefined`, the reference will be collected, as will the object if that was the last reference to it. So you're not preventing any garbage collection by doing this. The variable is now holding a completely different value... the `undefined` value, which I assume is a single value having a single place in memory. It's tough to tweak things on a small level. But if you could reuse the objects, that should help.

Comment: Also, prototypal inheritance can help with memory. Can't say for sure with the little information provided.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I can't think of the term for what I'm meaning there. Basically "a simple object that can be encoded to JSON". Maybe a better way to ask this is are local variables that don't allocate an object just pushed onto a stack as they are in C? Eg, do these references get destroyed immediately as they fall out of scope or do they have to be garbage collected?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive about this, but it might help if you cleared out the objects in code, with a wipe function. I found this interesting article that might help you more: https://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript

In particular I would look at this:

```
You can actually re-cycle an existing object (providing it has no prototype chain) by
deleting all of its properties, restoring it to an empty object like {}. For this you
can use the cr.wipe(obj) function, defined as:

    // remove all own properties on obj,
    effectively reverting it to a new object
    cr.wipe = function (obj)
    {
    for (var p in obj)
    {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p))
            delete obj[p];
        }
    };
```

That or set them equal to nothing, for example if an array is used, set its length to 0, that way later it won't have to be garbage collected when you reassign it

Comment: Seems funny that the code does a `.hasOwnProperty()` check before a `delete` operation.

Comment: We're actually using something like that elsewhere and it seems to have helped. Here, though, these are just references to other objects (or numbers). We don't want to destroy the object referenced, just don't want to create thousands of references that fall out of scope and need to be cleaned up.